# If I wrote "for deposit only:" on the back of a check, then crossed it out can I cash it at WalMart?

Tags: check, cashier-check

I received my state refund I tried mobile deposit with my bank but it wont take it because it is to me and my wife. I already wrote "for deposit only on the back". If I were to take it to Walmart to cash it and put a line through it with my initials in front of them can they cash it.

Comment: Do you have a joint account? Is the check made out to "A or B" or "A and B"?

Comment: What happens if you both sign on the back?

Comment: Normally if you both sign the back and then put for deposit only they will take it no issue, me and mine do it all the time. They should have given you a reason and how to correct it.

Comment: You'll have to ask Walmart, but my guess is that they'd decline cashing it just for the sake of avoiding complications.